# What happens when a mirror is placed before a concave lens?

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses

[image]
Recently i saw a video on YouTube where someone made a data glass which uses convex lens, from what i know convex lens create virtual image when the object distance is shorter than the focal length, i would like to know why he used a mirror before that.

Video link: https://youtu.be/lkl6yVauCKg

Answer (score 1):

The mirror is just to direct the light to the eye: the light is directed no matter if an image is real or virtual. Consider two mirrors: for example if you look in a mirror and have another mirror behind you to show the back of your head, the mirror behind you also makes a "virtual" picture, which you can see at the mirror before you. You just have to have the light rays go to your eyes, not to the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if i remove the mirror and just put the displa there, the data will still show it on the reflector same as before without any change?

Comment: @Jurjur: If you remove the mirror and place the display there - yes you could see the image but it would be laterally inverted. Then you might need to make some changes to the software to accommodate for the inversion (simply just invert the source image). However, it would no longer be longitudinally compact as in the above image.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks. So the mirror is for direct the light and to show the image properly (not inverted)?